# kendo editor saved text formatting not displaying on SSRS report

Tags: html, reporting-services, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-editor

I am trying saved valued from Kendo editor on an SSRS report.

The problem I am having is the Underline of text is not working.

In Kendo editor, if I save the text as underline, it is saving in the database as

```
<span style="text-decoration:underline;"></span>
```

and SSRS is not able to recognize the above code even though if the placeholder is set to HTML

I also tried in kendo adding custom tool which adds

```
 <u></u>
```

tags... but kendo is even changing that also.

Can anyone please let me know if there is a solution or alternative for this problem